# What should i use for a local database in a windows 8 metro app

Tags: c#, database, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to write a media management Metro app for windows 8 and I want to store all my metadata for the app in a file based database that should only be usable by the app.
Ive already made a similar app for windows 7 and I used Sql Compact for the data but im not sure if sql compact is compatible with win8.

So what should I use for storing data in a Metro app?

Comment: SQL Server CE is a no-go for metro-ui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using IndexedDB, if you use Metro app javascript, no need third party libraries to accessed it. because Metro app javascrip using the same engine with IE10.

Comment: Whats the speed of IndexedDB like, is it comparable to SQL CE?

Comment: It would appear that this is the only viable option at the moment... which means if youre using xaml/c# youre plum out of luck

Answer (score 1):

SQLITE is one I'm using with great success.  It just exceeded my expectations.  Very portable...

Comment: Will an app using SQLite pass the app verification process?, Ive read that SQLite uses win32 calls that are not allowed in metro

Comment: @Lightweight: Not sure if SQLite, when compiled under windows, makes API calls that are deemed illegal for "metro apps."  Until I read your reply, I wasn't aware that metro apps involved preclusion of what I guess would normally be backward compatibility; seems odd.

Comment: just read a comment from Tim Heuer from Microsoft saying that SqlLite will not pass the current store validation process

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winappswithcsharp/thread/1e03b3e7-7659-4407-ac07-a5a3db7a178c